# Android re-use XML layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

How can I name an XML layout and use it in another layout? Let's say I have the following defined:

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/drawer_itemName"
     android:textColor="#ffffff"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and I want to call this **Avatar** so in another XML I can do like this:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/itemLayout"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"

<Avatar />    <!-- THIS -->
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the `<include/>` tag.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use `include` tag to re-use layout:

```
<include layout="@layout/Avatar"/>
```